# call two methods is once

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to javascript and stack overflow and I ask for your help because I got stuck.

So here I have two methods. The first method dynamically creates a select dropdown menu from a list [members].state

The second method removes the duplicates from the list and keeps only unique data from the list. Both of the methods are working very well using console.log. I have already shown my data in a select menu but I can't remove the duplicates.

The question is: How to combine those two methods to call each other and to be able to work together?

I am looking forward to your opinions and I wish I one day gain the skills to help other people from this amazing community.

```js
function getCities() {
    for (var i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {
        var opt = members[i].state;
        var el = document.createElement("option"); //create option
        el.textContent = opt; //create text space
        el.value = opt;
        select.appendChild(el); //assign the text
    }

}
getCities();



function removeDuplicates(arr){

    let unique_array = [];
     //   let test = [];


    for(let i = 0;i < arr.length; i++){
        if(unique_array.indexOf(arr[i].state) == -1){
            unique_array.push(arr[i].state);
          test.push(arr[i].state);

        }

    }
    console.log(test);

    return unique_array;
}
removeDuplicates(members);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the filtering function from within the getCities function and use that filtered list as the origin of the members array.

UPDATE - just edited the original array to be an array of objects - to give you the state property that you needed in you OP. Refresh and you will see that even though there are duplicated objects in the original array - there are only the 3 unique values being passed to the select list.

Note that you could have the filtering as part of the single function - but I left it as a separate function to give you the experience of calling another method with the array as a parameter.

I also changed the for loops to a more modern forEach loop to give a modern flavour to the solution.

```js
var arr = [
 { name: 'test1', state: 'test-state-1'},
 { name: 'test1', state: 'test-state-1'},
 { name: 'test2', state: 'test-state-2'},
 { name: 'test2', state: 'test-state-2'},
 { name: 'test3', state: 'test-state-3'}
];

getCities();


function getCities() {
  var filteredMembers = removeDuplicates(arr);
  console.log(filteredMembers);
   
    filteredMembers.forEach(function(member){
        var opt = member;
        var select = document.querySelector('select');
        var el = document.createElement("option"); //create option
        el.textContent = opt.state; //create text space
        el.value = opt.state;
        select.appendChild(el); //assign the text
    })
}


function removeDuplicates(arr){
 
    var unique_array = [];
    var tempArr = [];

   arr.forEach(function(item){
        if(tempArr.indexOf(item.state) == -1){
           unique_array.push(item);
           tempArr.push(item.state);
         }
     });

    return unique_array;
}
```

```html
<select></select>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help i appreciate that. I tried to do it but the console return that error  arr is not defined

Comment: sorry - took me a moment to construct the snippet - try my solution again

Comment: UPDATE - just edited the original array to be an array of objects - to give you the state property that you needed in you OP. Refresh and you will see that even though there are duplicated objects in the original array - there are only the 3 unique values being passed to the select list.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better not to depend on one function from another. And call them embedded.

```js
let members = [
 { name: 'test1', state: 'test-state-1'},
 { name: 'test1', state: 'test-state-1'},
 { name: 'test2', state: 'test-state-2'},
 { name: 'test2', state: 'test-state-2'},
 { name: 'test3', state: 'test-state-3'}
];

getCities(removeDuplicates(members));


function getCities(members) {
 let select = document.querySelector('select');
 for (let i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {
    let opt = members[i];
    let el = document.createElement("option"); //create option
    el.textContent = opt; //create text space
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el); //assign the text
}
}
 


function removeDuplicates(arr){

let unique_array = [];


for(let i = 0;i < arr.length; i++){
    if(unique_array.indexOf(arr[i].state) == -1){
        unique_array.push(arr[i].state);
    }
}

return unique_array;
}
```

```html
<select></select>
```

Comment: Guys Thank you very much for your support finally it works ,i feel so happy but i want to read the code a little bit to understand exactly the process. If i will have misunderstandings ll come back to you :) :) :) Thanks a lot both of you

Comment: arr.forEach(function(item) That line behave the same with the classic for?

Comment: Can i use in my methods the classic for instead of each because i understand it better?

Comment: With respect @Smollet777 - this is exactly the same as my solution with the one exception that you are calling removeDuplicates in a different location. I am calling getCities - which calls removeDuplicates - you are calling getCities(removeDuplicates) -. It doesn't matter which approach -but this does not seem to be an improvement on my solution and muddies the clarity for a new member. I have no issue with a solution using mine or even saying my approach is crap - but simply altering the order of calling  two functions and all other code is the same is neither an improvement or an advantage.

Comment: @Smollet777 - its not about credit - I clearly state that anyone can use / modify or reject my code - my point was that your approach is functionally exactly the same as mine and the practise of passing values, arrays and objects from one function to another is a basic JS skill that is used universally. My issue was simply that your solution stated that it was better to not have one function call another and use its return values - and this is simply not true.

Comment: @IoanDimi I replaced back `forEach` with `for` for your better understanding

Comment: Guys both of the approaches are working very well and my credits are going to both of you and i appreciate the time that you waste for me. To be honest i have some misunderstandings about the functions and how call each other but i try to make it clear

Comment: @gavgrif but function reusability decreases with each dependency. For example, we will want to display all options **with** dublicates. For this you will need to change the function, and this is a violation of the SOLID principles

Comment: @IoanDimi I don't deserve any credits. gavgrif was the first. I just wanted to clarify how it would be better in my opinion. (note how I also replaced outdated `var` for `let`. I recommend you to read about it.)

Comment: @Smollet777 I participate in a coding bootcamp and i have receive a lot of information in sort time and i try to manage them. I get confused and i am not sure that i will succeed finally but till then i ll give all of my effort. The bad thing for me is that they don't teach theory and i lose my mind while i am reading "javascript and jquery interactive front end". I will read about the difference between var and let :) :)

Comment: @IoanDimi In short, `var` is outdated and `let` is improved version.
P.S. Learning is hard. My main advice is not to give up.